# Trying to display image in another form

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a chat program using C#. In my program I have an emoticon form that has the list of emoticons. I want to display those in my richtextbox in the main form. Any idea how? I am stuck trying to solve this. I really have no idea how.

BTW, the emoticons are buttons. I have already tried displaying them in a textbox but only in the same form. I want it to display into the richtextbox of the main form whenever I click the emoticon.

[image: This is my main form]

[image: My emoticon]

Well, the only code that I've tried is displaying it on a richtextbox in the emoticon form, like this:

```
public void Image(Bitmap displayPic)
{
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(displayPic);
    DataFormats.Format imgFormat = DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    if (richTextBox1.CanPaste(imgFormat))
    {
        richTextBox1.Paste(imgFormat);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The data format provided is not supported by this control.");
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.shocked);
    Image(bit);
}
```

Comment: I would say that best way is to implement as modal window and return selected smiley

Comment: please add code for what you tried

Comment: Your question is quite vague. What exactly have you tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Needs some more information... is the emoticons window a popup, or is it a side form? Is the problem "putting an image in a rich text form" or the communication between the two forms? Since it's a chat, I assume the emoticons have some kind of string codes associated with them for transferring?

Comment: Let's put it this way. Is there a way to access the richtextbox of another form?

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this using clipboard:

**Emotion Form:**
On click of emotion you have this code:

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
Image img = Image.FromFile(fname)
Clipboard.SetImage(img);
f1.insertImotion()
```

**Chat Form:**

```
public void insertImotion(Clipboard)
{
RichTextBox1.Paste();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! you answered my question. Although, not exactly but thanks.

Comment: That'll create a _new_ `Form1` from the smileys Form though, not access the existing one. I'm quite sure that's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you just need to set up a communications system. In cases like these, you usually don't access the rich text box directly, instead you ask the form *nicely* to "please insert this emoticon into the text".

This can be done by giving your main form a public function to insert said smiley, giving your emoticons form a constructor accepting the main form's object type, and storing that main form's object in a private variable in the emoticons form, so you can make the call on it at any time.

For thread safety, Delegates should be used to access any UI stuff in a different form, since it runs on another thread. You should google around a bit to find out more about that.

```
Form MainForm
{
    // Button to open the smileys window. Note you give "this" (MainForm)
    // to the EmoteForm so it can call this object's public functions.
    private void btnOpenEmoticons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // open the smileys window, giving this as parameter
        EmoteForm emoticons = new EmoteForm(this);
        emoticons.Show();
    }

    // Delegates are always needed to access user interface stuff from external
    // sources, since they generally run on different threads.
    private delegate void InsertEmoticonDelegate(RichTextBox rtb, String emotCode);

    //The function you call from the emoticons form
    public void InsertEmoticon(String emotCode)
    {
        // Invoke and Delegate are needed for thread safety:
        // you're asking this nicely, not stuffing it in there.
        chatTextBox.Invoke(new InsertEmoticonDelegate(AddEmoticon), chatTextBox, emotCode));
    }

    // needs to match the Delegate so it can be called with Invoke
    private void AddEmoticon(RichTextBox rtb, String emotCode)
    {
        // perform code to add the image defined by the "emotCode" string
        // into the rich text box "rtb".
    }
}
```

And for the emoticons form:

```
Form EmoteForm
{
    private MainForm m_MainWindow;

    // public constructor
    public EmoteForm (MainForm mainWindow)
    {
        this.m_MainWindow = mainWindow;
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    // The smiley button you click
    private void somesmileybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.m_MainWindow.InsertEmoticon(":D");
    }
}
```

Communications will happen as follows:

- `btnOpenEmoticons` is clicked, creating a new `EmoteForm` object giving the main form as parameter, and then showing that form.
- On `EmoteForm`, `somesmileybutton` is clicked. Calls `m_MainWindow`'s public `InsertEmoticon` function with string ":D"
- `chatTextBox` is (nicely) asked to please find a spot in its busy schedule to execute a function of the `InsertEmoticonDelegate` type, meaning one with a `RichTextBox` and a `String` as parameters.
- The actual given parameters for this delegate are `AddEmoticon` as the function to execute, and the rich text box itself and the string ":D" as its parameters.
- The `AddEmoticon` function is executed, and figures out from the given argument which smiley to put into the given rich text box.

Of course, you can actually give the Image object instead of the smiley code string like I did, but I dunno... seems simpler to me to manage those with codes.

---

As for the actual inserting of an image into the rich text... the simplest solution seems to be be to make a backup of whatever's currently in the clipboard, then put your image into the clipboard, then paste it in the rich text box, and then restore the clipboard's original contents. Sounds ugly, but it works, apparently. Once you got your Image object, this should do the trick:

```
IDataObject originalClip = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
Clipboard.SetImage(img);
rtb.Paste();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(originalClip);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use clipboard to perform this.

try this code:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile(fname)
Clipboard.SetImage(img);
RichTextBox1.Paste();
```

Comment: I've already tried that. I think that only displays the image on the same form. I really want it to display it to another form. Well, is there a way to access the richtextbox of another form?

Comment: Look have to pass into another form constructor this data and you can access. For example on the click of emotion you generate clipboard object and pass as a constructor argument and that constructor perform the insertion operation in richtextbox.

Comment: Watch my another answer.